# How to set values in a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, pixel

I am working with a 2-d numpy array which looks like this:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

So I have numpy inside numpy which has a list of four values (pixels in RGBA to be specific). I want to set all values to 0. What is the most pythonic way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would be a 3D array. For example you obtain that from `np.zeros((3,100,4), dtype=np.int8)`

Comment: Hmm, you are correct! So here I am copying my numpy array from another numpy array and setting all values to zero. What is the most efficient way to do that? Can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m[:] = 0
```

would set all values of your array `m` to zero.

If you need an array of zeros with the same shape and datatype of `m`, use:

```
np.zeros_like(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(10, 10)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
```

`b` will be an `ndarray` of exactly the same shape as the original, filled with `0`.