# Pixel manipulation in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pixel-manipulation

I want to convert all pixel values 0 instead of the value of 255. Pixel values are kept in Numpy array, namely x and:

```
x.shape = (100, 1, 256, 256)
```

How to manipulate arrays with the condition?

I tried the below but the error occured "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

```
i=0
for i in x[i]:
    if x[i]==255:
        x[i] = x[i]
    else:
        x[i] ==0
```

Comment: If x.shape = (100, 1, 256, 256) you can't set it to a single value since it has more than one dimension. Also your first if-clause does nothing, you could just just check for the condition that doesn't apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set values in a 2d numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011304/how-to-set-values-in-a-2d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
x[x==255] = 0
```

Test:

```
# Repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(42)

# Synthesise array
x = np.random.randint(0,256, (100, 1, 256, 256), np.uint8)

# Count number of 255s
len(np.where(x==255)[0])    # result = 25671

# Make each 255 into 0
x[x==255] = 0

# Count number of 255s
len(np.where(x==255)[0])    # result = 0
```